# Set specific range for int in scala

Tags: scala, range

```
class Test(val myInt :Int){}
```

I want that for myInt only 0 to 10 must be allowed.So how to specify range for member variable in scala with val type.

Comment: You mean you want to add validation on myInt?

Comment: I believe there is a way this could be accomplished via compile time, type level programming in [Shapless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough to know exactly how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply adding `require` or whatever which throws an exception when it gets invalid value solves your issue.

```
class Test(val myInt :Int){
  require(0 <= myInt && myInt <= 10)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Give [Refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) a look. It allows you to create range types which are checked at compile time.

Your range would look like this:

```
type InMyRange = Interval.ClosedOpen[W.`0`.T, W.`10`.T]
```

and you can create a value of this type like so:

```
refineMV[InMyRange](0) 
// Refined[Int, InMyRange] = 0
refineMV[InMyRange](9) 
// Refined[Int, InMyRange] = 9
```

In the error cases:

```
refineMV[InMyRange](-1) 
// Left predicate of (!(-1 < 0) && (-1 < 10)) failed: Predicate (-1 < 0) did not fail
refineMV[InMyRange](10) 
// Right predicate of (!(10 < 0) && (10 < 10)) failed: Predicate failed: (10 < 10)
```